# Find a matrix with optimization Python Scipi

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to calculate the solution to the following equation: `0 = WB-S` for `B`, while setting upper and lower bounds for the results. The matrices have the following shape:

```
W is mxn
B is zxn
S is mxz
```

I have tried using the `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear` function of `scipy`. However, I run into the following error:

> `b` must have at most `1` dimension.

In this case, `b` is `S` on my equation.

```
df_ret.shape
(2414, 97)
df_matrix.shape
(2414, 336)
df_bd.shape
(97,)
lb = 2,5*df_bd
up = -2.5*df_bd
res = lsq_linear(df_matrix, df_ret, bounds = (lb,up))
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 res = lsq_linear(df_matrix, df_ret, bounds = (lb,up))
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_lsq\lsq_linear.py
>   in lsq_linear(A, b, bounds, method, tol, lsq_solver, lsmr_tol,
>   max_iter, verbose)
>       261     b = np.atleast_1d(b)
>       262     if b.ndim != 1:
>   --> 263         raise ValueError("`b` must have at most 1 dimension.")
>       264 
>       265     if b.size != m:
>
> ValueError: `b` must have at most 1 dimension.

Comment: That's what the documentation says: `b : array_like, shape (m,)`.  And the return array, `x : ndarray, shape (n,)`.  In other words the linear equation is of the form `A*x=b`, where `A` is 2d, but `x` and `b` 1d.  You could run this `z` times to handle other dimension.

Comment: Your description is broken. The dimensions you gave would not allow valid matrix-multiplication. If you mean to solve it for `B_ = B.T`, it's possible, but not natural for `lsq_linear`.